# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) error when changing a value

Tags: python, json

When i pass a key like `1234567890` into this funtion to add one to its value `uses`

```
def addUse(key):
    with open ("keys.json") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        for i, d in data["keys"]:
            if(d["key"] == key):
                d["uses"] = d["uses"] + 1

    with open ("keys.json", "w+") as f:
        json.dump(data,f)
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jlp02\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 104, in redeem
    await addUse(key)
    for i, d in data["keys"]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jlp02\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jlp02\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This is what the keys.json file looks like

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "key": 92001134281235250,
      "role": "MODERATOR",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 69745445001637090,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 23658745999062060,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 23606241449357936,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 2577578387864023,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 23025062092625228,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 71812399761452820,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 43292816397532480,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 28871100160463480,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 58856807043840170,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    },
    {
      "key": 14934056480328052,
      "role": "Supporter",
      "Server": 753230650181550100,
      "uses": 0,
      "maxuses": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `for i, d in data["keys"]` why this? `data["keys"]` is a `list`

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

i just had to remove the `i` in the

```
for i, d in data["keys"]:
            if(d["key"] == key):
                d["uses"] = d["uses"] + 1
```

so it would be

```
for d in data["keys"]:
            if(d["key"] == key):
                d["uses"] = d["uses"] + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

`data.keys()`
For any dictionary returns a view of the **keys** in the dictionary as defined in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys).

You would probably want to try something like this if you want to iterate over the key-value pairs in the dictionary

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    ...
```

Comment: `my_dict.keys()`? is it `items()`?